# Check if Tesseract is 64 bit or 32 bit

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I installed Tesseract a few months ago and am facing some issues now. I'm trying to run 'ocrmypdf' library but it isn't compatible with the Tesseract version I have. I'm trying to check if the Tesseract on my system is 32 bit or 64 bit. Does anyone know how to do that?

I've used `tesseract --version` and an getting the response below

```
tesseract v5.0.0-alpha.20191030
 leptonica-1.78.0
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.3) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE
 Found libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.3 bz2lib/1.0.6 liblz4/1.7.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check with where `tessearact` got installed in your `C` Drive.

One of the easiest way that 32bit application gets installed on 64bit OS in below folder

```
“C:\Program Files (x86)”
```

Whatever the application is installed under this directory could mean that application is `32bit`

Ex:

[image]

If you are not able to find here, then it will be located in `C:\Program Files` that will be `64bit` application.